# setTimeout works in Opera, but not in other browsers

Tags: javascript, browser, settimeout

I hit the dead end with this one, scratching my head for half a day already. The problem is quite strange, if you'd care to look at my source code: www.modwebsolutions.com/test2 (warning: not optimized yet, might lock browser for a few seconds). Problem is, that sequence of setTimeouts works ok in Opera, but in other browsers only first one is executed and then execution of the script stops. Exerpt from my code:

```
var a1=setTimeout(drawVertical([arguments]),1000);
var b1=setTimeout(drawVertical([arguments]),1000);
var c1=setTimeout(drawVertical([arguments]),1000);      
var d1=setTimeout(drawVertical([arguments)],1000);
```

Tried everything, enclosing function in quotes, looking for other syntax errors, nothing helped. And the strange thing is as I mentioned - everything works ok in Opera.
UPDATE: also works in Chrome, and that makes it even more confusing...

UPDATE2: same example without timeout, works just fine (though slow): www.modwebsolutions.com/test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done here is called a function before setting the timeout.  Immediately when the code sees `drawVertical([arguments])`, it is going to call that function.  The return value of that function is what you are passing as your first argument into `setTimeout`, so unless `drawVertical` returns a function, this won't work.

So you could get this to work by giving `setTimeout` a function to call:

```
var args = arguments;
var a1=setTimeout(function() { drawVertical([args]); },1000);
...
```

EDIT: I set the outer `arguments` to an `args` variable, since the `arguments` would be different in the inner function.

Comment: Tried the anonymous function method - it's working on almost all the browsers, BUT... browsers slows down even more, and the most weird thing - all the lines produced by the function also have some thick black shadow, which is totally unexplainable and not logical. What can setTimeout have in common with canvas line styling?...

Comment: `setTimeout` wouldn't cause your browser to slow down, but perhaps you are calling it more times than you think, and therefore calling `drawVertical` more times than you think?  Perhaps the thick black line is a result of drawing the line many times near the same spot?  I'd put an `alert` or a `console.log` somewhere to make sure this function is acting the way it is supposed to.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the parameters for you function **after** the function and timeout. Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout)

```
var a1 = setTimeout(drawVertical, 1000, [arguments]);
```

Comment: I tried to use this structure - the result is the same like with anonymous function - the lines on canvas rendered by drawVertical function all have some terrible black shadow which I definitely did not add. Just to note that without timeout everything works just fine: www.modwebsolutions.com/test